# Cannot run git command from within build tool chain on Azure hosted build

Tags: python-2.7, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to do something simple. At least I thought it should be simple.

We are using an Azure DevOps hosted build with a python based toolchain. The source code was checked out with git on this build machine and is working fine.

Inside this toolchain I would like to retrieve some information from git. I tried to use

```
options = ['show', '-s', '--format=%ae', 'HEAD']
cmd = "git" + options 
subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```

(I hope I did not do a syntax error in this example, I simplified some parts)

The message I get on the build server is:

```
ERROR git not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
in __git    return subprocess.check_output(cmd) File d:\a\1\s\tools\python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 566, 
    ...
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I also tried to use an absolute path with the typical windows pathes but was not able to locate git on the hosted build machine.
I also had a look into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

This looks to me like it should be possible to just use git. Hmmm. Does anyone have ideas for me?

Comment: What's your hosted environment? Hosted Ubuntu agent? Or hosted VS agent? The git installation info in them are different with each other. Since we do not know the details on your toolchain, I can not sure it is calling `git.cmd` or `git.exe`. For example, we pre-installed the git.exe in VS2017 agent. But your toolchain want to calling `git.cmd`. At this time, it will prompt the errror git not found. See this [github issue](https://github.com/uber/ludwig/issues/74)

Answer (score -1):

Check if your Agent has Git capability enabled.

1. Go to manage agent pool page
2. Select your agent pool
3. Select the agent
4. Go to capabilities tab
5. Check if git is added.

If not added just click on Add button and set /usr/git capability

Comment: He uses Microsoft hosted agent, in those agents git is installed.

Comment: Per the original post: *The source code was checked out with git on this build machine*. That means Git is installed. This is not a correct answer.